# Getting Bad State Value error trying to toggle variables

Tags: variables, tkinter, state

I'm stuck on this code. I'm getting a Bad State Value (_tkinter.TclError: bad state value "SkyBlue1": must be normal, hidden, or disabled) but I am not sure what is wrong. Can anyone advise?

```
from tkinter import HIDDEN, NORMAL, Tk, Canvas

def toggle_eyes():
    current_color = c.itemcget(eye_left, 'fill') #check eye - white is open, blue is closed
    new_color = c.body_color if current_color == 'white' else 'white' #sets eye to opposite value
    current_state = c.itemcget(pupil_left, 'state')
    new_state = NORMAL if current_state == HIDDEN else HIDDEN
    print(new_state)
    c.itemconfigure(pupil_left, state=new_state)
    c.itemconfigure(pupil_right, state=new_state)
    c.itemconfigure(eye_left, state=new_color)
    c.itemconfigure(eye_right, state=new_color)

def blink():
    toggle_eyes() #close the eyes
    root.after(250, toggle_eyes) #wait 250 milliseconds and open the eyes
    root.after(3000, blink) #wait 3000 milliseconds, then blink again
    
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
#sets the canvas size

c.configure(bg='dark blue', highlightthickness=0)
#sets the background color

c.body_color = 'SkyBlue1'
body = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
ear_left = c.create_polygon(75, 80, 75, 10, 165, 70, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
ear_right = c.create_polygon(255, 45, 325, 10, 320, 70, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
foot_left = c.create_oval(65, 320, 145, 360, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
foot_right = c.create_oval(250, 320, 330, 360, outline=c.body_color, fill=c.body_color)
eye_left = c.create_oval(130, 110, 160, 170, outline='black', fill='white')
pupil_left = c.create_oval(140, 145, 150, 155, outline='black', fill='black')
eye_right = c.create_oval(230, 110, 260, 170, outline='black', fill='white')
pupil_right = c.create_oval(240, 145, 250, 155, outline='black', fill='black')
mouth_normal = c.create_line(170, 250, 200, 272, 230, 250, smooth=1, width=2, state=NORMAL)
#make the pet

c.pack()
#arranges components in the Tkinter window

root.after(1000, blink)
#blink after 1 second of starting the program

root.mainloop()
#starts the function that listens for input events like mouse clicks
```

I tried setting the variables to normal or hidden first. I also tried using print statements to determine where the problem was happening. It seems to me that current_state is a null value although I can't figure out why. The pet blinks once but seems like the next time the function is called (to blink again) is when the error occurs.

Any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to set the fill color on the following two lines:

```py
c.itemconfigure(eye_left, state=new_color)
c.itemconfigure(eye_right, state=new_color)
```

But you used wrong keyword `state`. `fill` should be used instead:

```py
c.itemconfigure(eye_left, fill=new_color) # used fill keyword
c.itemconfigure(eye_right, fill=new_color) # used fill keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

In the lines 11 and 12, Change from `state` to `fill`. I have removed `c.configure` in the initial configuration and added the configuration value in the c -widget itself. Removed the declaration `c.body_color = 'SkyBlue1'` and changed all the `c.body_color` into `'SkyBlue1'`. Works fine.

```
from tkinter import HIDDEN, NORMAL, Tk, Canvas

def toggle_eyes():
    current_color = c.itemcget(eye_left, 'fill') #check eye - white is open, blue is closed
    new_color = 'SkyBlue1' if current_color == 'white' else 'white' #sets eye to opposite value
    current_state = c.itemcget(pupil_left, 'state')
    new_state = NORMAL if current_state == HIDDEN else HIDDEN
    print(new_state)
    c.itemconfigure(pupil_left, state=new_state)
    c.itemconfigure(pupil_right, state=new_state)
    c.itemconfigure(eye_left, fill=new_color)
    c.itemconfigure(eye_right, fill=new_color)

def blink():
    toggle_eyes() #close the eyes
    root.after(250, toggle_eyes) #wait 250 milliseconds and open the eyes
    root.after(3000, blink) #wait 3000 milliseconds, then blink again
    
root = Tk()
c = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg='dark blue', highlightthickness=0)
#sets the canvas size




body = c.create_oval(35, 20, 365, 350, outline='SkyBlue1', fill='SkyBlue1')
ear_left = c.create_polygon(75, 80, 75, 10, 165, 70, outline='SkyBlue1', fill='SkyBlue1')
ear_right = c.create_polygon(255, 45, 325, 10, 320, 70, outline='SkyBlue1', fill='SkyBlue1')
foot_left = c.create_oval(65, 320, 145, 360, outline='SkyBlue1', fill='SkyBlue1')
foot_right = c.create_oval(250, 320, 330, 360, outline='SkyBlue1', fill='SkyBlue1')
eye_left = c.create_oval(130, 110, 160, 170, outline='black', fill='white')
pupil_left = c.create_oval(140, 145, 150, 155, outline='black', fill='black')
eye_right = c.create_oval(230, 110, 260, 170, outline='black', fill='white')
pupil_right = c.create_oval(240, 145, 250, 155, outline='black', fill='black')
mouth_normal = c.create_line(170, 250, 200, 272, 230, 250, smooth=1, width=2, state=NORMAL)
#make the pet

c.pack()
#arranges components in the Tkinter window

root.after(1000, blink)
#blink after 1 second of starting the program

root.mainloop()
#starts the function that listens for input events like mouse clicks
```